# I was learning ROS2NAV2, following the documentations, when I launched the file, The ODOM TF started moving itself in the space

Tags: navigation, ros, robotics, slam, rviz

I am learning ROS2 NAV2, created a URDF file, it runs perfectly in Gazebo...But after 20-25 seconds the ODOM Tf automatically starts moving upwards or sometimes goes down it the grid, For the code, I have literally copy pasted from the documentations twice, getting the same issue. Please do help if you have the solution.
[ODOM TF moves away from the robot automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odvix.png) 
[Rviz shows no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPamx.png)

I tried to go through the documentations and copy paste my code from it. But tbh I feel there is some issue in the code itself...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.